# Glide: log each request

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-glide

Consider the code below:

```
Glide.with(<your_context>)
    .load(<remote_file_url, local_file_path>)
    .into(<imageview>);
```

Above Glide code is written in lots of file.
Simply I want to log my **remote_file_url** or **local_file_path** in logcat. But I don't want to change the code in every file.

Is Glide allowing logging? If it allows, then I need a simple central way to turn on glide logging.

For Reference: I want the way like `Retrofit + okhttp` allow. In `OkHttp`, I just have to add interceptor at one location and it will log information about each webservice call without writing any other additional code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In [Glide 4.0 RC](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases/tag/v4.0.0-RC0) that's possible via [Glide configuration](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#configuration): you can configure `Glide`'s logging level via [`GlideBuilder#setLogLevel(int)`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/3761a432c0f58fd77cd9d06314a1c6c17bca35f0/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/GlideBuilder.java#L245).

Having `MyGlideModule.java`:

```
@GlideModule
public class MyGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
  @Override
  public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
    builder.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
  }
}
```

Then you'll be able to see following log in console:

[image]

---

For older versions (`3.x`), as mentioned in ["Debugging workflow"](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Debugging-and-Error-Handling#debugging-workflow):

> To view how and when Glide's internal engine finds the resources you asked for, you can enable logging:
>
> `adb shell setprop log.tag.Engine VERBOSE`
>
> `adb shell setprop log.tag.EngineJob VERBOSE`
>
> `adb shell setprop log.tag.DecodeJob VERBOSE`

This will prompt with following output:

[image]

You can enable only `Engine` logging if you are not interested in other logs.

Comment: thanks for answer. But it seems that `builder.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);` is only available in glide v4 version while i am using 3.7.0.

Comment: And in latest version i am not able to use `PlaceHolder` also.

Comment: Nope, haven't got a chance yet. But would certainly consider moving to, regardless it's in "release candidate" stage or no.

Comment: Yep it's in RC version.
In v4 there is no need to give meta data in manifest.
When I add meta data it gives me exception `Expected instanceof GlideModule, but found:<Package>.<MyModule>`. 
And also there are annotation available from v4. So no need to add it in meta data.

Comment: The original answer I gave was not tailor-made for v4, it's just that I knew that Glide may be configured from modules. I believe there must be a better approach with v4.

Comment: Can you implement v4 and update the answer then i will accept it, Currently `setLogLevel()` is in v4, while meta data is not supported in v4(i thought), So if i accept this answer it may misguide to audience, ..
If you can't update it, then don't worry i will edit your answer and will accept it. BTW thanx for your effort.

Comment: Is it possible to enable Engine logs in V4? 
`adb shell setprop log.tag.Engine VERBOSE` doesn't work