# How to log each request url from Glide?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide

I have using Glide to download images for quite a long time, so the code like this are every where:

```
      GlideApp.with(getContext())
            .load(imgUrl)
            .into(imgView);
```

And suddenly I need to log every image's url for further analysis. Instead of searching every usage of Glade and changing the code like this:

```
      GlideApp.with(getContext())
            .load(imgUrl)
            .listener(requestListener) // log urls through listener
            .into(imgAd);
```

is there any way that I could add the requestListener globally like in the default options of Glide so that I don't need to search and change every Glide usage throughout the application?

I use Glide v4 and I have checked the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602131/glide-log-each-request) which log the urls directly to logcat but not to my local storage for further analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glide 4.9.0 can set default requestListener.

link https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases/tag/v4.9.0
 https://github.com/bumptech/glide/commit/37127f0f817d4a11dfdcc447946397b5288de593

In Custom AppGlideModule

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
        builder.addGlobalRequestListener(new RequestListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Object> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Object resource, Object model, Target<Object> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In Custom Activity Fragment

`GlideApp.with(object).addDefaultRequestListener()`

`Glide.with(object).addDefaultRequestListener()`

Comment: It works! The v4.9.0 release arrives just in time. Thanks.